# How to Load or Cue a playlist using PierfrancescoSoffritti 12.0.0. library

Tags: android, kotlin, playlist

I've managed to implement PierfrancescoSoffritti library and obtained almost all functionality from the deprecated youtube android API, except I'm unable to load a playlist. I've read that the library was extended to implement this option but is not available in the code. Can someone show an example of how to load  playlist in PierfrancescoSoffritti library?

This is the code I use, it is still a work in the progress. the problem is loadPlaylist...is not available...

var youTubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view)
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(youTubePlayerView)

```
    youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
        override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
            val videoId = "MZPTKmm4Dy4"
           /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           //cannot load playlist by calling a function here
           //youTubePlayer.loadPlaylist(videoId, 0f)
           /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0f)
            youTubePlayer.play()

        }

        override fun onStateChange(
            youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer,
            state: PlayerConstants.PlayerState
        ) {
           // super.onStateChange(youTubePlayer, state)

            if(state == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.PLAYING)
            {
                //to implement code
            }
            if(state == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.ENDED)
            {
                //to implement code
            }
            if(state == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.PAUSED)
            {
                //to implement code
            }
            if(state == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.UNKNOWN)
            {
                //to implement code
            }
            if(state == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.BUFFERING)
            {
                //to implement code
            }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you go to github repository there is an activity called "PlaylistExampleActivity".

Basically, you need to follow the code below.

```
val iFramePlayerOptions = IFramePlayerOptions.Builder()
        .controls(1)
        .listType("playlist")
        .list(PLAYLIST_ID)
        .build()
```

I hope you understand this code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35401346)

Comment: To Michele: My answer is pretty easy to understand if you check the github repo. I don't understand why you asked me the clarification.